# Clarification on the HTML5 pubdate attribute

Tags: html

Can some one explain to me in layman's terms what the following sentences, from the [W3C specification working draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-time-pubdate), below mean about the `pubdate` attribute for the time element below.

> For each `article` element, there must be no more than one `time` element with a `pubdate` attribute whose nearest ancestor is that `article` element. Furthermore, for each Document, there must be no more than one time element with a `pubdate` attribute that does not have an ancestor `article` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that time value is related to time when article is published. That is info for robots or some machine which reads content.

```
<article>
 <header><h1>Article Title</h1></header>
 <footer>Published on <time pubdate>2009-08-30</time>.</footer>
 <p>I put a bike bell on his bike.</p>
</article>
```

As above, the time tag is used to tell for instance to google search engine when article was published in public.

Ancestor, means, nearest parent article tag for time tag. Ancestor can be grand parent or grand grand parent. Depends how much time tag is nested deep in DOM tree. It can be N-th generation child while no article tag is in between.

Comment: This is actually slightly incorrect. If the `pubdate` attribute exists on a `<time>` element, then the element must also have a `datetime` attribute.

Comment: Actually, the current version of the spec does not require a datetime attribute, though it is certainly best practices to use one. When used without a datetime attribute, I assume the text child of the time element should have a string that is un-ambiguous about the date (something that, say, php's strtotime() function could clearly parse)

Comment: It makes sense to use those two parameters together since textNode of `<time>` tag will contain probably either partial of date or locale formatted date string

Answer (score 2):

These 2 sentences should be considered separately :

> For each article element, there must be no more than one time element with a pubdate attribute whose nearest ancestor is that article element.

This means that for a list of *article* elements you may include as much *time* elements as you want, but **only one** may have a pubdate attribute. This make sense because this pubdate refers to the article which may have only one published date.

> Furthermore, for each Document, there must be no more than one time element with a pubdate attribute that does not have an ancestor article element.

The same case applies for a whole document (an HTML page). While you may have has much time element as you want in your page, **only one** may have a pubdate attribute which is refering the publication date of the page it-self.
As an example look at [one free Bestkicker poker Video](http://www.bestkicker.com/videos/392-construire-1-bk-en-micro-limite-1.html)

I hope it helps you.

**Note** : The new version of the link you provided do not mention **pubdate** anymore. There is a proposal to drop it from the spec.

Comment: Does anyone know what would be the "correct" substitution for `pubdate` now that it's vanished?

Comment: @LayZee Use `itemprop="datePublished"`. [Example](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-article-element.html).